# Choose correct html tag via jQuery in Grails

Tags: jquery, ajax, grails-2.0

I have 2 select boxes, one with car names and second with car models, when I choose car name(e.x. BMW) second select box must update with car models belongs to BMW. I create this logig with jQuery. but the problem is that, my web designer create really cool select box design with css3 and for it he need hidden input and select tag with identical ID attribute(e.x. id="car_model"). and when I call the jQuery function it is updates the hidden input and populate it with options. how I can choose select with id="car_model" instead of hidden type with the same id="car_model".

**controller:**

```
class HomeController {

def index() {
    def cars = Car.list();
    render (view: '/index', model:[cars:cars])
}

def getModels(params) {
    def models = Models.findAll {
        car.id == params.id
    }
    println(models)
    withFormat {
        html {
            render(template:'/select',model:[model:models])
        }
        json {
            render models as JSON
        }
    }
}
```

}

**view:**

```
<div class="row field_select">
                <label class="label_title">Select Maker:</label>                    
                <g:select class="select_styled" name="car_maker" from="${cars}"
                    optionKey="id"
                    optionValue="name"
                    noSelection="['':'- Choose a car -']"
                    onchange="${remoteFunction(
                        action:'getModels.json',
                        onSuccess:'getCarModels(data)',
                        params:'\'id=\' + this.value' )}"/>

            </div>
            <div class="row field_select" >
                <label class="label_title">Select Model:</label>
                <select class="select_styled" name="car_model"></select>
            </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
function getCarModels(data) {   
var $element = $('#car_model');
$element.empty();
$.each(data, function(id, modelName) {
  var option = $('<option/>').val(id).text(modelName);
  $element.append(option)
});
}
```

EDIT:[image]

Comment: ids should never be the same - you can use the same name on the inputs but use different ids, if the grail plugin requires you to have identical ids I wouldn't use it

Answer (score 0):

The id of `html` elements is supposed to be unique, you can assign a class to select to select it using `class selector`. The hidden field wont get the class of select and you would be able to differentiate it.

```
var $element = $('.selectclass');
```

You you havee no other option but having two elements with same id and different type then you can select by adding `type` of `tag` in selector

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/F7Z5F/)**

```
var $element = $('select[name=car_model]');
```

Comment: In your question you mentioned id=car_model but it is name. So this requires the selector on name not on id. $('select[name=car_model]') will give you the select you are going for

Comment: I have added live demo, you would have better idea here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/F7Z5F/

Comment: I understand what u mean, but it not resolved the problem again